# Set up tinydns on home wireless network

Tags: wireless-networking, dns

I've got a 2701HG-B Gateway wireless router at home and I'd like to set up [TinyDNS](http://cr.yp.to/djbdns/tinydns.html)
 or another tool that'll help me set up DNS resolving on my local network. Basically I want to be able to type in things like `http://kevin/` and display a page while I'm at home.

Is the router running a full Linux? Can you SSH into it or is there another way to modify the local DNS settings?

Comment: If there are not too many clients/PCs, just modify their hosts file, it's much simpler.

Comment: How many computers or mobile-devices are connected to your wireless lan?
Setup a dedicatet pc running Linux and perhaps TinyDNS.